# ¿a que error se refiere cuando creo un directorio en local en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

Creo una función para descargar un directorio de Servidor FTP y intento crearlo antes en local y me salta un error

```
def Down_Dir(ftp, dir):

    ftp.cwd('\datos')
    try:       
        os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+"\\"+dir)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise      

    os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"\\"+dir)
```

este es el error que me da:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pruebas_Arrays.py", line 267, in <module>
    conexionFtp(elemento[0],elemento[1],elemento[2],elemento[3],elemento[4],elemento[5],elemento[6], marcaTiempo, elemento[7])
  File "Pruebas_Arrays.py", line 136, in conexionFtp
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fich, open(rutaLocal + fich, 'wb').write)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 442, in retrbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 399, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 365, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 273, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 246, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550
```

Comment: El código que muestras no es el que está causando el error. En el _stacktrace_ que has volcado puedes ver que el error sucede en la línea 136 de tu programa, cuando haces `ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fich, open(rutaLocal + fich, 'wb').write)`. El error lo genera el servidor, no el cliente. `550` significa que no tienes permiso para acceder al fichero que intentas descargar. Probablemente porque no exista. Ten cuidado además con las "barras inversas", que no tienes duplicada en `ftp.cwd()`. Además, si el servidor es un Unix usará "la otra barra" `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esto solucionará tu problema pero lo mejor a la hora de trabajar con directorios es usar [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) De esta forma tu programa sería:

```
def Down_Dir(ftp, dir):

    ftp.cwd('\datos')
    try:       
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),dir)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise      

    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),dir))
```